# How to replace backslashes to a different character in a string Python

Tags: python, string, replace, backslash

I want to know how to use Python's `str.replace()` function (or similar) to replace Backslashes...

When i try to do it:

```
>>> temp = r"abc\abc"
>>> temp.replace(r'\'', 'backslash')
'abc\\abc' # For some reason, temp.replace() does not replace '\' with 'backslash' even when using raw variable
>>> temp.replace(r'\\', 'backslash') # Same result
'abc\\abc'
```

How do i fix this? And why? (Linux, Debian/Ubuntu, x86_x64 processor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash -

```
temp = r"abc\abc"
temp.replace('\\', 'backslash')
'abcbackslashabc'
```

Comment: The important thing here is to *not* use `r` (raw string) for the single backslash, because `r'\\'` is a string with two backslashes. Yes, it's confusing.

Comment: I understand... ```\\``` is like a shortcut or alias to ```\```... and ```r'\\'``` is actually two backslashes